# Common mode input voltage range and comparators on an MCU

Tags: microcontroller, comparator, common-mode

The comparators on my MCU, a dsPIC33FJ128GP802, give the common-mode input range as AVdd-1.15V. AVdd is 3.3V, so does this mean the comparators can't compare voltages in the range of 2.15V to 3.3V?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, that is what it means.

Comment: What happens if you try to compare in this range?

Comment: You can't complain to Microchip if it doesn't work.

Comment: @Thomas - If you want to be able to complain, you need to use a voltage divider to get it in the required range.

Comment: I don't want to complain, I want to know what actually happens, like does it no longer compare properly or is it slower than usual, or what...?

Comment: If you operate outside the common-mode range, you can see things like oscillating output or an outright incorrect output.

Comment: If you exceed the 2.15V on any of the inputs the comparator will give you unpredictable output. Software way to say this is that part will have catastrophic loss of precision with very high probability of wrong result. If you exceed about 3.5..4V the input protection diodes will pass the excessive current to power line and dissipate energy elsewhere over all circuit.

Answer (score 2):

In terms of actual behavior, one may imagine each input of a comparator has having up to five operational regions, which I'll call "way too high", "slightly too high", "good", "slightly too low", and "way too low".  If either input is "way too high" or "way too low" there's no guarantee as to what the comparator will do (it may attempt to source or sink a larger-than-specified amount of current to/from the inputs, or arbitrarily report either input as being higher than the other, etc.)  If both inputs are "slightly too high" or both are "slightly too low", the comparator may arbitrarily report either input as being higher than the other.  The comparator will work correctly in the seven other cases where both inputs either are "good" or only "slightly" out of range.

Unfortunately, many comparator data sheets fail to make a distinction between "slightly out of range" and "way out of range", even though in practice some (if not most) designs would behave as though they are no worse than "slightly out of range" for all values within their Absolute Maximum Ratings.